# How to insert a string-token before occurrence of another string-token in a string with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this

```
'I am a beautiful string ABC where sometimes ABC there ABC are weird tokens ABC'
```

I need to insert another token, let's say `'123'`, before any occurrence of the token `'ABC'` in my string.
In other words the result I want to obtain is

```
'I am a beautiful string 123ABC where sometimes 123ABC there 123ABC are weird tokens 123ABC'
```

I have tried several solutions, but none looks to me elegant. Any suggestion to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
console.log(
  'I am a beautiful string ABC where sometimes ABC there ABC are weird tokens ABC'
  .split("ABC")
  .join("123ABC")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the string by searching for `ABC` and add a prefix `'123'` to the found substring.

```js
var string = 'I am a beautiful string ABC where sometimes ABC there ABC are weird tokens ABC',
    result = string.replace(/ABC/g, '123$&');

console.log(result);
```